# prevent ant design modal outside clicking closing modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

we are using react and ant design as the frontend tech. One thing I noticed in the ant design modal. When we put onCancel attr in the modal like the code below. This will allow us can close the modal by clicking the 'X' in the right corner but it will also allow closing modal by clicking anywhere outside the model. Is there a way to prevent this outside click action while keeping the 'X' action ? Thanks in advance

```
            <Modal
            visible={visible}
            title="My modal"
            onOk={handleOk}
            onCancel={closeMyModal}
            className='myModal'
        >
```

Comment: Check the API for questions like this. Looking through it, it seems there's a `maskClosable` property that controls this, that you would set to false. https://ant.design/components/modal/#API

Comment: @Jayce444 thanks a lot. how come I missed that set up in the API doc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add

```
maskClosable = {false}
```

to prevent closing the modal dialog when the mask (area outside the modal) is clicked

```
<Modal
  visible={visible}
  title="My modal"
  onOk={handleOk}
  onCancel={closeMyModal}
  className='myModal'
  maskClosable={false}
  >
```

Comment: but we can close the modal by press the ESC button. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set property `maskClosable` by false to prevent it

Answer (score 1):

According to Antd's documentation, you have two solutions:

1. If you use the `<Modal>` in your component, you'd to set `maskClosable={false}`. This prevents you from viewing the modal when you press outside the modal area.
2. You can check `Modal.confirm()` as follows:
   https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-confirm